# Does countable intersection of linear subspaces with finite codimensions have countable codimension?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be a vector space. Let $F_1, F_2, \dots$ be linear subspaces with finite codimensions in $E$. WLOG we can take the codimensions of the $F_n$'s to be 1. Is it true that $E/(\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}F_n)$ has countable dimensions?

Comment: Do you see how to reduce this situation to one involving a countable nested chain of subspaces, $V_1 \supseteq V_2 \supseteq \ldots $, ?

Comment: Do you mean $V_n=F_1\cap F_2\cap \dots \cap F_n$?

Comment: What is a codimsension

Comment: @hardmath Which way are we going? To show it true or to show it false?

Comment: @Amr the codimension of subspace $W$ in a vector space $V$ is the dimension of $V/W$.

Comment: Thanks. So maybe take $F_n=\{f: f(q_n)=0\}$ where $\{q_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$?

Comment: Play with the ideas for a bit.  I think that might work with a different choice for $E$ than the one I suggested (because square-integrable functions are only defined "almost everywhere"), but there's something along these lines one can do.

Answer (score 2):

It is false. Take $E=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and take $F_n$ to be the kernel of the $n$th projection. Then $\cap _{n\in \mathbb{N}}F_n=0$.

Comment: Good example.  I was thinking along the lines of taking $F_n$ to be the square-integrable functions $L^2[0,1]$ orthogonal to $x^n$, so each $F_n$ has codimension 1, but $V_n = F_0 \cap \ldots \cap F_n$ would be functions orthogonal to polynomials of degree $n$.  By a standard result (see [here Lemma 1](http://www.math.washington.edu/~dumitriu/555_24.pdf)) the intersection of the $V_i$'s will be the trivial subspace.